# Notepad++ Display Printing Page Count

Tags: printing, notepad++

I have a rather large document i want to print via Notepad++, but i can't get the page count before printing. Is there a way to do it? (Assume standard 8.5"x11" paper)

Comment: Does Notepad++ have a print preview option which would give you (at least) an approximate page count?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That really isn't the purpose of Notepad++. While a print preview function might be a good feature, Notepad++ is geared more toward helping keep code organized, differentiating files, etc.

If you want to see how many pages it is before hand, try printing to PDF first. At least then you have a digital version and are able to see how many pages it is. I recommend [PDFCreator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator) to do this.

Good luck!

Comment: This approach is also very useful as a print preview for Notepad++ to see if the line wrapping will do anything strange.

Answer (score 4):

You probably already have the [Microsoft XPS Document Writer](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/xps/viewxps.mspx) printer installed on your machine.  You could print your document using the XPS Document Writer to see how many pages it will be.

*Note*: XPS documents can be opened by double-clicking or opening in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

I counted how many lines you can have in the default font. It appears that one page is 52 lines in default font. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

open it with word... Set the margins same as your notepad ++ margins

Answer (score 0):

Go by the Line Number, on Screen. I find 64 lines (in Total) can print on an A4 paper. The Line Numbers, on screen, correspond to Line Numbers on A4 paper.